# Calling Java Methods from Php

Tags: java, php, hessian

I have an application with php at front end and Java as Backend. I was using Hessian from php to call Java methodes with returns data from Java to php. and now i got some problem with hessian and I am getting some exception u can see the question i posted earlier.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121340/hessianserviceexporter-only-supports-post-requests

**Is there any other method to call java functions from php code, just like hessian?**

If so can someone tell me know?

Comment: Can we add this beans.xml in Application context. or i have one servelet handling .xml file called web.xml

And also i have one more doubt is.. Should i add service in the Class DemoService as service ("demoService")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to implement a REST layer using JAX-RS. Apache CXF is an excellent, very simple system for deploying JAX-RS services. You can build out the entire service layer without having to worry about Java/PHP interaction that way.

To give you an idea of how easy it is:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class DemoService {
    @GET
    @Path("sayHello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() { return "Hello, world!"; }
}
```

The content of the beans.xml for CXF's servlet would look like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<jaxrs:server id="demoService" address="/demoService">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serviceBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="serviceBean" class="com.company.DemoService"/>
```

Comment: Can we add this beans.xml in Application context. or i have one servelet handling .xml file called web.xml

Comment: Can we add this beans.xml in Application context. or i have one servelet handling .xml file called web.xml

And also i have one more doubt is.. Should i add service in the Class DemoService as service ("demoService")